# swift 3.0 multiple selection with Select All option

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

i have  added data in table view and i have manually added "select all" option in to list at first position now when user select first option which is select all then all item in to list  should be selected and deselected when choose same. i have tried code below but its not working so can any one help  me to solve this

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = ObjTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SelectUserCell
    for i in 0 ..< self.getStudentName.count {
        cell.btnCheckbox.setImage(UIImage(named: "selectedItem"), for: .normal)
        print (i) //i will increment up one with each iteration of the for loop

    }

}
var unchecked = true
 @IBAction func btnCheckBoxClick(_ sender: Any) {

if unchecked == true {
           //(sender as AnyObject).setImage(UIImage(named: "selectedItem"), for: .normal)
            cell?.btnCheckbox.setImage(UIImage(named: "selectedItem"), for: .normal)
            //unchecked = false
            let cello = ObjTableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)
            print(cello!)
            ObjTableview.reloadData()
        }else
        {
            //(sender as AnyObject).setImage(UIImage(named: "unSelectedItem"), for: .normal)
            cell?.btnCheckbox.setImage(UIImage(named: "unSelectedItem"), for: .normal)
           // unchecked = true
        }
}
```

Comment: In cell for row you are setting only  `UIImage(named: "selectedItem"` and why for loop ? only last value of array been applied , Other problem i can see is  `btnCheckBoxClick` where you are updating  `unchecked` value

Comment: Make your logic on Array. once data load in array put all zeros and when you select any cell change that index value to 1. and when u selectAll in Array put all 1. and when u unselectAll put All zeros in array.

Comment: **Never ever** dequeue a table view cell outside of `cellForRow...`. That's a fatal mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jayprakash, You are almost there. You need to modify some lines -

**Here is your modified code snippet**

```
var unchecked:Bool = true

@IBAction func btnCheckBoxClick(_ sender: Any) {

    if(unchecked){

        unchecked = false
    }
    else{

        unchecked = true
    }


    ObjTableview.reloadData()


}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if(indexPath.row == 0){

            btnCheckBoxClick(sender: UIButton())

      }

 }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

        let cell : SelectUserCell!
        cell = tableView .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SelectUserCell", for: indexPath) as! SelectUserCell
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none


       if(unchecked){

              cell.btnCheckbox.setImage(UIImage(named: "unSelectedItem"), for: .normal)

         }
       else{

              cell.btnCheckbox.setImage(UIImage(named: "selectedItem"), for: .normal)
         }


   // Do your stuff here

   return cell
}
```

Hop it will simplify your code structure.

Comment: When selecting first, all the cells are selected, but when the second cell is selected, all the cells are made, only if I select the first cell only then it will be done only

Comment: @JayprakashSingh Here are the scenarios: 1. Select all cells only when you select first cell right.

So what will happen when you select other cells?

Comment: Selection of the second cell is done all only I see from the first cell

Comment: Okay you mean to say Select | Unselect all cells will be performed on your first cell selection only.

Comment: @ amir khan Yes